# Missing data when filling four-dimensional array in R

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, matrix, modeling

Good day.

I am attempting to convert a long format dataframe, to a four-dimensional array using `for` loops. The array has to contain year/plot/replicate matrices for each of the *N* bird species. The goal is to ultimately model species occupancy over multiple seasons/years.

(PS this code is adapted from a R package vignette but I cannot get a hold of the author in time)

The problem I experience though, is that the loops run through each combination of year/plot/replicate, for each species, in order to fill detection (1) and non-detection (0) data for the species but, the output contains `NA`s and zero counts under each species (see near the end).

I attached the first 10 rows of my long dataset ([download from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9pba86w24jam6o/y.long.csv?dl=0)) for your use.

```
# Load the relevant package
library(dplyr)
```

Use a data import function of your choice to import the CSV file (download above).

```
# Species codes
sp.codes <- sort(unique(y.long$Species))
# Plot codes
plot.codes <- sort(unique(y.long$Plot))
# Years
year.codes <- sort(unique(y.long$Year))
# Number of species
N <- length(sp.codes)
# Maximum number of replicates per plot
K <- 10
# Number of plots
J <- length(unique(y.long$Plot))
# Number of years
I <- length(unique(y.long$Year))
# Array for detection-nondetection data
y <- array(NA, dim = c(N, J, I, K))
# Label the array dimensions
dimnames(y)[[1]] <- sp.codes
dimnames(y)[[2]] <- plot.codes
dimnames(y)[[3]] <- year.codes
# Let's have a look at the array structure
str(y)

 logi [1:7, 1, 1:4, 1:10] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "343" "347" "351" "352" ...
  ..$ : chr "1"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "2008" "2010" "2011" "2012"
  ..$ : NULL
```

The array contains the following matrices:

- 7 species
- 1 plot
- 4 years
- 10 replicates

The above looks correct when compared to the vignette example. Now for the filling of the array...

```
for (i in 1:I) { # Loop through years.
  for (j in 1:J) { # Loop through plots in each year.
    for (k in 1:K) { # Loop through replicates at each plot and in each year.
      # Extract data for current year/plot/replicate combination.
      curr.df <- y.long %>%
        filter(Year == I[i], Plot == J[j], Replicate == K[k])
      # If plot j was sampled during replicate k in year i, 
      # curr.df will have at least 1 row (i.e., at least 
      # one species will be observed). If not, assume it 
      # was not sampled for that replicate.
      if (nrow(curr.df) > 0) {
        # Extract the species that were observed during
        # this year/plot/replicate.
        curr.sp <- which(sp.codes %in% curr.df$Species)
        # Set value to 1 for species that were observed.
        y[curr.sp, i, j, k] <- 1
        # Set value to 0 for all other species.
        y[-curr.sp, i, j, k] <- 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...no errors; however...

...the outputs are as follows:

```
str(y)
 logi [1:7, 1, 1:4, 1:10] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "343" "347" "351" "352" ...
  ..$ : chr "1"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "2008" "2010" "2011" "2012"
  ..$ : NULL
# Total number of observations for each species
apply(y, 1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
343 347 351 352 399 401 736 
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

No data?!

The above code was adapted from a vignette where the dataset was filtered using a single year (which equated to a three-dimensional array as the year or time matrix was not required/included). Thus, I attempted to add the year matrix into the code snippets as per above.

An important consideration for this array I attempt to create, is that with the years added, plot/replicate combinations will be duplicated from one year to the next because replicates are dates when birds were surveyed.
For example, if the first survey in one year took place in January and the first survey in another year in November, both will be coded *Replicate = 1* etc. I wonder whether this "duplicated" data structure is the cause of my undesired output despite filtering/grouping for each year/plot/replicate combination?

The final output should look similar to the example (from a different dataset) below; however, no vignette exists for adding the year into the array (as explained above).

A CORRECT example array below (note the detection and non-detection data that filled in as well as the replicate codes):

- 12 species
- 373 plots
- 9 years
- 3 replicates

```
 $ y       : num [1:12, 1:373, 1:9, 1:3] 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  .. ..$ : chr [1:12] "AMRE" "BAWW" "BHVI" "BLBW" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:373] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:9] "2010" "2011" "2012" "2013" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can use `tapply`, no need for `for` loops:

To make sure I'm getting the numbers I expect, I'll change one `count`:

```r
quux$count[2] <- 2
```

And the call (edited to fix a paste-typo):

```r
ary <- tapply(
  quux$count,                                        # values summarized in each cell
  quux[, c("Species", "Plot", "Year", "Replicate")], # dimensions and labels
  FUN = sum, default = 0)

dim(ary)
# [1] 7 1 4 1
str(ary)
#  num [1:7, 1, 1:4, 1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
#   ..$ Species  : chr [1:7] "343" "347" "351" "352" ...
#   ..$ Plot     : chr "1"
#   ..$ Year     : chr [1:4] "2008" "2010" "2011" "2012"
#   ..$ Replicate: chr "1"

ary
# , , Year = 2008, Replicate = 1
#        Plot
# Species 1
#     343 0
#     347 0
#     351 0
#     352 0
#     399 0
#     401 0
#     736 1
# , , Year = 2010, Replicate = 1
#        Plot
# Species 1
#     343 2
#     347 0
#     351 0
#     352 1
#     399 1
#     401 1
#     736 1
# , , Year = 2011, Replicate = 1
#        Plot
# Species 1
#     343 1
#     347 0
#     351 0
#     352 0
#     399 0
#     401 0
#     736 0
# , , Year = 2012, Replicate = 1
#        Plot
# Species 1
#     343 1
#     347 1
#     351 1
#     352 0
#     399 0
#     401 0
#     736 0
```

Original data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Date = c("2008-11-12", "2010-12-06", "2010-12-06", "2010-12-06", "2010-12-06", "2010-12-06", "2011-11-27", "2012-02-05", "2012-02-05", "2012-02-05"), Year = c(2008L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L), Species = c(736L, 343L, 352L, 399L, 401L, 736L, 343L, 343L, 347L, 351L), Replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2",  "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I received an "argument "INDEX" is missing, with no default" error running your code per se; however ChatbotGPT assisted after which I did a small mod. See my answer below which I think is what I need and using `data.table` allowed for a swift computation on more than 17,000 observations.

Answer (score -1):

Using my large dataset the following worked as per my comment to  above...

```
  y <- tapply(
    y.long$count,
    y.long[, c("Species", "Plot", "Year", "Replicate")],
    FUN = sum,
    default = 0
  )
  str(y)
```

Call:

```
 num [1:10, 1:171, 1:15, 1:59] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ Species  : chr [1:10] "137" "343" "347" "351" ...
  ..$ Plot     : chr [1:171] "1" "10" "100" "101" ...
  ..$ Year     : chr [1:15] "2008" "2009" "2010" "2011" ...
  ..$ Replicate: chr [1:59] "1" "10" "11" "12" ...
```

Comment: I do not see any difference in your code.

Comment: The additional `tapply()` before creating the array and you had 3 open brackets and 2 closed. Fact of the matter, it is amazing that such a simple workaround seemingly produced the results I required. Thanks again.

Comment: Yup, paste mistake